# passing parameters of a function to another function when using metatable

Tags: lua

im learning lua and got to metatable part, in this example

```
local tb = {}
local meta = {}

function tb.new(s)
local super = {}
super.s = s

setmetatable(super,meta)

return super
end

function tb.add(s1,s2)

return s1.s..s2.s

end

meta.__add = tb.add

f= tb.new("W")
t= tb.new("E")

print(f+t)
```

in this part

```
function tb.add(s1,s2)

return s1.s..s2.s

end
```

how are values from  `super.s` passed to  `tb.add` function. i noticed that the variable `s` in s1.s and s2.s in `return s1.s..s2.s` seems to be the link between `tb.new` and `tb.add`.

and in this part

```
f= tb.new("W")
t= tb.new("E")
print(f+t)
```

when compiler gets  to `f+t` i think this function is called first  `f= tb.new("W")`  in this function right now there is no  `s2`  so it should be nil how did `return s1.s..s2.s` happen?

Comment: The code does not work as is. It needs `local tb = {}`, and then it seems to work

Comment: ya i forgot to add it i will edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a table `tb`. Otherwise it results in an error for indexing a nil value.

Your code creates two table values with a field `s = "E"` and `s = "W"` respectively. Both have share the same metatable `meta` that implements the `__add` metamethod.

From the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manuual 2.4 - Metatables and Metamethods](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4)

> Every value in Lua can have a metatable. This metatable is an ordinary
> Lua table that defines the behavior of the original value under
> certain events. You can change several aspects of the behavior of a
> value by setting specific fields in its metatable. For instance, when
> a non-numeric value is the operand of an addition, Lua checks for a
> function in the field __add of the value's metatable. If it finds one,
> Lua calls this function to perform the addition.

So for `f+t` will call `meta._add(f, t)` which returns `f.s..t.s`

Answer (score 0):

`tb.new` basically just creates a new table and returns it, so in this code:

```
f= tb.new("W")
t= tb.new("E")
```

... `f` and `t` are newly created tables, each with an `s` field and both with the same metatable.

The interpreter automatically calls `meta.__add` when it sees `f+t` and passes both operands as arguments. `tb.add` has two parameters and assumes both of them have an `s` field which is a string, so that all checks out perfectly. If `t` was not a table with an `s` field, *then* you would be in trouble.

In other words, `tb.new` does not pass `s` to `tb.add`. `tb.new` stores `s` inside the new table, and `tb.add` retrieves that value from its parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,its seems i need to study fields.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @lhf and answered by @Piglet the code is not working as is.
So here is a corrected version that uses/show new Lua 5.4 `warn()`.
It can be used for debugging because `@on` and `@off` let you control the output.
Here it is...

```
if warn==nil then warn=print else warn('@on') end
local meta={}
local tb={}

function tb.new(s)
 warn('tb.new("'..s..'")')
 local super={}
 super.s=s
 setmetatable(super,meta)
 return super
end

function tb.add(s1,s2)
 warn('__add('..tostring(s1)..', '..tostring(s2)..')')
 return s1.s..s2.s
end

meta.__add=tb.add

f=tb.new("W")
t=tb.new("E")

print('Print: ',f+t)
```

Output is...

```
Lua warning: tb.new("W")
Lua warning: tb.new("E")
Lua warning: __add(table: 0x5661f510, table: 0x5661f580)
Print:  WE
```

( On earlier Lua versions than 5.4 `print()` is used instead of `warn()` )